# jenkins how to run from jenkins gradle specify testng.xml

Tags: jenkins, gradle, automation

I'm working with jenkins and try to call a remote machine that has a java project with gradle config to run tests build.gradle
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

```
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
version = '1.0'


sourceSets {
    jars
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: "src/jars/resources", include: ['*.jar'])
    compile group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version: '6.9.10'
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '3.+'
    compile group: 'io.appium', name: 'java-client', version: '4.1.2'
    compile 'com.testdroid:testdroid-api:2.9'
    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20141113'
}

compileJava {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
}

test {
    useTestNG {
        suites 'src/main/resources/testng.xml'
    }
}
```

but I want to run a custom testng2.xml! so I define in jenkins a parameter test and define their testng2.xml, but and it will show in the console

```
/Users/jenkins/Home/workspace/AutomationGradle/gradlew -Dtest=testng2.xml  clean test -i
```

but I can't understand how to make gradle to get the dynamic parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use it like that, with a default value set to `testng.xml`

```
ext.testFile = System.getProperty('Test_Plan') ?: 'testng.xml'

test {
    useTestNG {
        suites "src/main/resources/$testFile"
    }
}
```

And run your command line with the `test` parameter

```
/Users/jenkins/Home/workspace/AutomationGradle/gradlew -DTest_Plan=testng2.xml  clean test -i
```

Comment: This is correct answer. Ideally, add command line usage, please

Comment: still does not working from some reason always go to "testng.xml", what is the "ext"? i need more info

Comment: ext.testFile = System.getProperty('Test_Plan') ?: 'testng.xml'

test {
    useTestNG {
        suites "src/main/resources/${testFile}"
    }
}

Comment: please change the project to system because I'm sending the -D parameter and not the -P and add {} to testFile  @ToYonos

Comment: Edited. But using project properties should be better isn't it ?

Comment: probably yes but send parameters from jenkins send it as -D

Comment: I think in Jenkins it can be set as project properties too but anyway, it works either way.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I'v worked a lot of time on this, so I'm writing what worked for me:

In the Jeninks I added a parameter:
    TESTNGFILE

```
In the groovy file:    
-DTestNG=$TESTNGFILE

build.gradle:

ext.testFile = System.getProperty('TestNG') ?: 'regression.xml'


test {
useTestNG {
    options {
        systemProperties(System.getProperties())
    }
    systemProperties = [
            TESTNGFILE: System.getProperty('TESTNGFILE')
    ]
    suites "/src/test/resources/testng/${testFile}"
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
    useDefaultListeners = true
 }
}
```